# Use previous row value in 'FOR XML PATH' in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having the following tables:

```
TABLE A (CUSTOMER_LOAN):
=============================
CUSTOMER_ID TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT 
XXX         100,000.00
YYY         200,000.00

TABLE B (SCHEDULE):
=========================================
CUSTOMER_ID SCHEDULE_DATE SCHEDULE_AMOUNT
XXX         20170102      30,000           
XXX         20170302      10,000           
XXX         20170602      15,000           
YYY         20170203      50,000           
YYY         20170403      100,000          
YYY         20170703      30,000
```

What I need is to get the following output:

```
EXPECTED REPORT OUTPUT :
=============================
CUSTOMER_ID  SCHEDULE_DATES                   SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
XXX          20170102/20170302/20170602       70,000/60,000/45,000  
YYY          20170203/20170403/20170703       150,000/50,000/20,000
```

The SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL is calculated by (Outstanding Principal - SCHEDULE_AMOUNT).
i.e. for customer XXX, (70,000 = 100,000 - 30,000)/(60,000 = 70,000 - 10,000)/(45,000 = 60,000 - 15,000)

Below is my query:

```
SELECT A.CUSTOMER_ID
, STUFF((SELECT '/' + SCHEDULE_DATE FROM SCHEDULE B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SCHEDULE_DATES
, STUFF((SELECT '/' + (A.TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT - CAST(B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT AS MONEY)) FROM SCHEDULE B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
FROM CUSTOMER_LOAN A
```

As you can see, the SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL was wrong because the TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT is constant and the calculation (A.TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT - CAST(B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT AS MONEY)) not accumulated in next row.

Any way to do that calculation that could output the result like the expected report? I am using SQL Server 2012. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I replace SCHEDULE_AMOUNT with SUM(B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) OVER(ORDER BY SCHEDULE_DATE):

```
SELECT A.CUSTOMER_ID
, STUFF((SELECT '/' + SCHEDULE_DATE FROM SCHEDULE B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SCHEDULE_DATES
, STUFF((SELECT '/' + CAST(A.TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT - SUM(CAST(B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT AS MONEY)) OVER(ORDER BY CAST(SCHEDULE_DATE AS VARCHAR(8))) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM SCHEDULE B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
FROM CUSTOMER_LOAN A
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the query. The B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT should be CAST as MONEY. Then I use your query, the system returned the following error: ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame cannot contain expressions of LOB type.

Comment: I updated my query, but you should not store date in varchar(max) column

Answer (score 1):

As two other answers detail, the central idea is `SUM() OVER ()` to obtain a running total. But let's also show off common table expressions, constructors, `CONCAT` and `CROSS APPLY` while we're at it. (In the original question, `CUSTOMER_LOAN` and `SCHEDULE` already exist as tables and can be left out of the CTE.)

```
WITH CUSTOMER_LOAN AS ( 
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        ('XXX', $100000), 
        ('YYY', $200000)
    ) AS CUSTOMER_LOAN(CUSTOMER_ID, TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT)
), SCHEDULE AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        ('XXX', '20170102', $30000), 
        ('XXX', '20170302', $10000), 
        ('XXX', '20170602', $15000), 
        ('YYY', '20170203', $50000), 
        ('YYY', '20170403', $100000), 
        ('YYY', '20170703', $30000)
    ) AS SCHEDULE(CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT)
), PRINCIPALS AS (
    SELECT 
        S.CUSTOMER_ID, 
        S.SCHEDULE_DATE, 
        L.TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT - SUM(S.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY S.CUSTOMER_ID 
            ORDER BY S.SCHEDULE_DATE
        ) AS SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
    FROM SCHEDULE S 
    JOIN CUSTOMER_LOAN L ON S.CUSTOMER_ID = L.CUSTOMER_ID
)
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, T.*
FROM CUSTOMER_LOAN CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT('/', P.SCHEDULE_DATE)
        FROM PRINCIPALS P
        WHERE P.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_LOAN.CUSTOMER_ID
        ORDER BY P.SCHEDULE_DATE
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''),
    STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT('/', P.SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL)
        FROM PRINCIPALS P
        WHERE P.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_LOAN.CUSTOMER_ID
        ORDER BY P.SCHEDULE_DATE
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
) T(SCHEDULE_DATES, SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
Principals as
(
select b.*,TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT-SUM(SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) over (partition by b.CUSTOMER_ID order by SCHEDULE_DATE)   principal  from CUSTOMER_LOAN a
inner join SCHEDULE b
on a.CUSTOMER_ID=b.CUSTOMER_ID
)
select
    CUSTOMER_ID
    ,(
    STUFF((SELECT '/' + SCHEDULE_DATE FROM SCHEDULE B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

    ) Schedule_Dates
    ,STUFF((SELECT '/' + (convert(varchar(255),cast(b.principal as money),1)) FROM Principals B 
         WHERE B.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
from CUSTOMER_LOAN a
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you want. The key bit is the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING which is what does the running totals.

```
CREATE TABLE #CUSTOMER_LOAN (CUSTOMER_ID INT, TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT 

DECIMAL(38,2));
CREATE TABLE #SCHEDULE (CUSTOMER_ID INT, SCHEDULE_DATE VARCHAR(8), SCHEDULE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(38,2));

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_LOAN ( CUSTOMER_ID, TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT ) VALUES (1, 100000.00);
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_LOAN ( CUSTOMER_ID, TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT ) VALUES (2, 200000.00);

INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (1,'20170102',30000.00);
INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (1,'20170202',10000.00);
INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (1,'20170602',15000.00);
INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (2,'20170203',50000.00);
INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (2,'20170403',100000.00);
INSERT INTO #SCHEDULE ( CUSTOMER_ID, SCHEDULE_DATE, SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) VALUES (2,'20170703',30000.00);

; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.CUSTOMER_ID,
        B.SCHEDULE_DATE,
        a.TOTAL_LOAN_AMOUNT 
            - SUM(B.SCHEDULE_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY A.CUSTOMER_ID 
                                           ORDER BY B.SCHEDULE_DATE 
                                           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL
    FROM #CUSTOMER_LOAN A
    INNER JOIN #SCHEDULE B ON A.CUSTOMER_ID = B.CUSTOMER_ID
)
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
    LEFT(MAX(SCHEDULE_DATES), LEN(MAX(SCHEDULE_DATES))-1),
    LEFT(MAX(SCHEDULE_PRINCIPALS), LEN(MAX(SCHEDULE_PRINCIPALS))-1)
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CTE2.SCHEDULE_DATE + '/' 
    FROM CTE CTE2
    WHERE CTE.CUSTOMER_ID = CTE2.CUSTOMER_ID
    ORDER BY CTE2.SCHEDULE_DATE
    FOR XML PATH('')
) D (SCHEDULE_DATES)
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CTE2.SCHEDULE_PRINCIPAL) + '/' 
    FROM CTE CTE2
    WHERE CTE.CUSTOMER_ID = CTE2.CUSTOMER_ID
    ORDER BY CTE.SCHEDULE_DATE
    FOR XML PATH('')
) P (SCHEDULE_PRINCIPALS)
GROUP BY CTE.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Don't use `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ...)`. This is equivalent to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), ...)` here, but that's anything but obvious. (Specifically, it does not work out to a length that's "long enough for the input argument, no matter what".) Using `VARCHAR` without length is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).